# String buffer in assembly code

Tags: string, assembly, buffer

I just have ended my code which allow to cover your password. It goes like this(FASM):

```
org 100h

mov cx, 16

petla:
mov ah,08h
int 21h
cmp al,0dh
je OK
mov ah,02h
mov dl,42
int 21h

cmp cx,0
je Fail
loop petla

Fail:

mov dl, 0ah
int 21h
mov dx, pass2
mov ah,9
int 21h
jmp koniec

OK:

mov dl, 0ah
int 21h
mov dx, pass
mov ah,9
int 21h
jmp koniec


koniec:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

pass db 'Password OK', 0Ah, 0Dh, '$'
pass2 db 'Password Fail', 0Ah, 0Dh, '$'
```

And now I need to print the genuine password. I know the string buffer is a must and how declaration of the buffer should look like but I don't really know how to use it and make it work. 
Calling for help :)
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Since your program allows the input of **15 characters** of password, you could setup the buffer with:

```
Buffer db 16 dup ("$")
```

You initialize the DI register before your *petla* loop and put the ASCII code you got from the DOS function in the buffer via a `stosb` instruction:

```
  mov  di, Buffer
  mov  cx, 16
petla:
  mov  ah,08h
  int  21h
  cmp  al,0dh
  je   OK
  stosb
  mov  ah,02h
  mov  dl,42
  int  21h
  ;;;cmp cx,0
  ;;;je Fail
  loop petla
```

Please note that compairing for CX=0 is useless just before the `loop` instruction in your code.

Comment: @Milo If this answer helped you and solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer. More on how to accept and why, please see this SO information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768